# extracting the values using grep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, grep

Sample String : a.txt

```
Reading:RG1:+ /user/reading/Monday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/Friday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/tet/**/*.txt:12
```

I am looking to extract the string

```
after + or - what ever the string i want it
```

using  :

```
cat a.txt | grep RG1|grep '+'| cut -d':' -f3| cut -d'+' -f2 |sed -e 's/ //
```

I am getting 
/user/reading/Monday

But i amlooking

/user/reading/Monday:12

Comment: I think answer accepted by you doesnt work for string containing '-' case. Because you are cutting only '+' ':' only (not '-')

Comment: i have same code for - also .. its working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your command, use `-f3-` because you want everything from the 3rd field to the end of the line.

```
cat a.txt | grep RG1|grep '+'| cut -d':' -f3-| cut -d'+' -f2 |sed -e 's/ //'
```

Comment: What is the purpose of sed -e 's/ //' here ?

Comment: That is what the OP wants. From the question: `I am getting /user/reading/Monday But i amlooking /user/reading/Monday:12`. I just fixed his command for him.

Comment: @larsmans he also says "after + or - what ever the string i want it "

Answer (score 3):

Use `egrep -o`:

```
$ egrep -o '/user/reading/[A-Z][a-z]+day:[0-9]+' a.txt
/user/reading/Monday:12
/user/reading/Friday:12
```

**Edit**: for your new example, use something like

```
$ egrep -o '/user/[^ ]*:[0-9]+' a.txt
/user/reading/Monday:12
/user/**/Friday:12
/user/**/*.txt:12
/user/tet/**/*.txt:12
```

Assuming no spaces in your paths.

Comment: i dont know what this path all the times .. like this :/user/reading/ .and it wont be all time same format like this .. some time it may be regex also

Comment: If it's not always this format, then please post what it will look like.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=[-+] ).*' a.txt
/user/reading/Monday:12
/user/**/Friday:12
/user/**/*.txt:12
/user/tet/**/*.txt:12
```

Change the characters with the square brackets to change which lines you select.