# extracting-the-values-using-grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

From [extracting the values using grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068244/extracting-the-values-using-grep)

```
Reading:RG1:+ /user/reading-2/Monday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/Friday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/tet-23/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG2:+ /user/reading-2/Monday:12
Reading:RG2:- /user/**/Friday:12
Reading:RG2:- /user/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG2:- /user/tet-23/**/*.txt:12
```

I have tried with this : 
cat a.txt | grep RG1|grep '-'| cut -d':' -f3-| cut -d'-' -f2 |sed -e 's/ //'

This wont work because  it will extract wrong path because some of + also having -

How to reslove this issue

Comment: Useless use of cat. You should omit `cat a.txt` and change your first grep to `grep RG1 a.txt`. This won't solve your problem but it is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
egrep "^[^:]*:RG1:-" a.txt | cut -d: -f3 | cut -b3-
```

Sample run:

```
$ cat a.txt 
Reading:RG1:+ /user/reading-2/Monday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/Friday:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG1:- /user/tet-23/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG2:- /user/tet-23/**/*.txt:12
Reading:RG2:+ /user/reading-2/Monday:12
$ egrep "^[^:]*:RG1:-" a.txt | cut -d: -f3 | cut -b3-
/user/**/Friday
/user/**/*.txt
/user/tet-23/**/*.txt
```

`"^[^:]*:RG1:-"` means "start with anything but `:` zero or more times, then a `:`, then a `RG1`, followed by `-`.

Comment: I may need to search only for RG1 then it wont work .. because i have  RG2 , RG3 in data ...

Answer (score 1):

You may try to get the complete "`RG1:+`" string, and then cut by space, for example:

```
grep "RG1:+" a.txt | cut -d" " -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with sed

```
sed -r -e '/:RG1:/s/.*:[+-] //;s/:[0-9]+$//' a.txt
```

Which will operate only on lines with `:RG1:` in them. You can generalize this for all lines:

```
sed -r -e 's/.*:[+-] //;s/:[0-9]+$//' a.txt
```

Or just lines with RG and a number

```
sed -r -e '/:RG[0-9]+:/s/.*:[+-] //;s/:[0-9]+$//' a.txt
```

If you want to keep the trailing :12 simply omit the final substitution, e.g.:

```
sed -r -e '/:RG[0-9]+:/s/.*:[+-] //' a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is alowed
 - or +

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /\AReading:RG[1-9]:[+-]\s+(.*)\Z/' file
```

only -

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if /\AReading:RG[1-9]:-\s+(.*)\Z/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this variation on the answer I gave to your previous question:

```
grep -Po '(?<=RG1:- ).*(?=:\d*$)' a.txt
```